# How can i know when somebody send me some bnb

Tags: web3js, bsc, decentralized-exchange, rpc

i created a contract and write a backend for it i will make a presell on my website and i am new on this things if my question is too easy sorry for that but i am almost spend 24 hours for this thing. So the question is i want to share my metamask bnb smart chain wallet on my website and clients will send me a bnb to buy some token and then i will store it on db after some day i will send them some token i tried this code but i cant cath any thing i tried it in mainnet also and spend some bnb for it but it doesnt work for me

```
const subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
    address: 'myadress'
}, function(error, result){
    console.log(result);
})
    .on("connected", function(subscriptionId){
        console.log(subscriptionId);
    })
    .on("data", function(log){
        console.log(log);
    })
    .on("changed", function(log){
        console.log(log)
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do an ICO contract?

You basically store the amount sent on your smart contract, and have a function that will go through the senders and send them your token?

But to answer your question, I know Moralis has a pretty good events tracking and writting to DB, so you might look into it to help you

Comment: hi actually i dont know how can i send bnbs to my own wallet from tokens wallet.
Actually i can send token functionally but is it possible when somebody send bnb to token wallet how can i get that bnbs and how can contract automatically send them their token and send bnb to my wallet i dont know i am new on solidity